# Configure apache to load special folder for specific port

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

How to configure Apache to load special folder when using special port ?

Document root is : `www\`
Now i want to load `www\folder\` when i enter `http://localhost:8090/` on url.

I think i should create a virtual host. but don't know how to configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes , you answered yourself. Here's a generic configuration

```
Server configuration

# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www
ServerName www.example1.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8090>
DocumentRoot /www/folder
ServerName www.example2.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

I am considering www.example2.org and www.example1.com pointing to 127.0.0.1 ie. localhost